# Probability that sampled data will fall within range?

Tags: statistics, terminology

What mathematical concept do I need to read about to answer the following question?

Given:

- A population with an unknown mean, variance.
- A sample with a known size, mean, variance.

What is the range of values for 95% of the population data?

I initially thought that confidence intervals answered this question, but per https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1967239/25814 they provide a statement about the population mean, not its data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Chebyshev's  inequality is what you're looking for.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality